# How to stop the remote logout in Skype?

Tags: skype, ubuntu-14.04

I am using skype 3 yrs back the problem was the I can't open my account in two places like mobile and desktop at a same time.

If I am using skype in ubuntu and opening the Skype on mobile same time it forcefully logout.

I am searching a lot for this. I am asking this question in skype forum but no help from that.

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail on exactly what is happening?

Comment: I am using ubuntu skype now.when i am opening the skype application in my mobile then the ubuntu skype gets logout forcefully

Comment: Are you using up-to-date versions? I have no problems with them. I use Skype for Ubuntu, Skype for Windows and the Skype Web App.

Comment: Yes the version is also up to date.some suggesions that open a new account is there any way to solve this?.i think the problem is remote logout command.how to reverse that command?

Comment: for testing i open a new account its working fine so why this problem in my account any idea?

Comment: Check your account options thoroughly?

Comment: checked already all the options but cant resolved this.